# How to handle the person touching repeatedly after multiple warnings?

Tags: india, acceptable-behavior

South girls from India are conservative compared to north and I am a conservative girl. I feel very uncomfortable if any guy(male) touches me.

One guy from my batch usually stays with north girls, who allows touching. So, he is habituated to touch girls.

He uses to display same kind of behaviour with me and hence I warned him personally and friendly not to do that. But, since it is his habit, he is still doing that and I cannot warn him every time he touches me.

I *feel* that there is no option other than not talking with him by avoiding him intentionally. Either I can warn him in public or I can scold him, which I feel rude.

How to handle him in polite manner so that he will not touch me again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate to a new coworker that I am not comfortable being touched?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-to-communicate-to-a-new-coworker-that-i-am-not-comfortable-being-touched), albeit this isn't a co-worker, however the question and solutions are quite similar?

Comment: It is not solving my problem, because I told him more than twice.

Comment: The third paragraph is to just tell my opinion on dealing the issue and I am in need of steps to stop the issue.

Comment: @enlighten_me: Same problem yes, but the cultural difference between India and UK may affect approaches ...

Comment: "One guy from my batch..." I'm not familiar with what "batch" means in this instance.  Could you explain?

Comment: @Joshua likely "batch of students" to refer to a class of students.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You say you have given him multiple warnings already. Even if it is his habit to touch girls in general, a second warning should have been enough.

Handling it in a polite way is warning him in private, which you have already done and does not seem to help. Giving him a warning in public shows him that you are serious and that there will be consequences if he continues to harass you. How far you have to escalate depends on weather your 'public warning' does have an effect on him.

Remember, it's your body he's touching. Letting him go on with his disrespectful behaviour just because you don't want to create an uncomfortable situation for him is the reason why he can keep doing it.

Comment: i like this answer, you should make him unconfortable instead of you being unconfortable, telling him to not touch you in front of other people should make him unconfortable, if that doesn't work, try to not talk to him at all even if you are in the same place.